# Lançar Janela modal

Tags: php, html

Estou tentando lançar uma janela após envio de email e depois matar a `session` e então redirecionar para a pagina index.

```
// Enviar email
$mail->Send();

//echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
echo "<script>alert('O boleto foi enviado para o e-mail informado!');</script>"; 
//destruir a sessão e redirecionar para a pagina principal
session_destroy(); 
header("Location: index.php");

}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
// Mensagens de erro do PHPMailer
echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
// Outras mensagens de erro
echo $e->getMessage();
```

}

Esta linha não está sendo chamada, está passando direto para `echo "<script>alert('O boleto foi enviado para o e-mail informado!');</script>"`; 
Como resolver?

Restante do código

```
// Realizando o envio do email
try {
    // Remetente
    $mail->AddReplyTo('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Meu Nome');
    $mail->SetFrom('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Meu Nome');

    // DestinatÃ¡rio
    $mail->AddAddress($email_cli, $cliente);

    // Assunto
    $mail->Subject = 'Boleto de Pagamento';

    // Mensagem para clientes de email sem suporte a HTML
    $mail->AltBody = 'Olá '.$cliente . " segue em anexo o boleto para o pagamento do seu pedido";

    // Mensagem para clientes de email com suporte a HTML
    $mail->MsgHTML('<p>Olá ' . $cliente . ' ! Obrigado pela preferência! 
    <br> Segue em anexo o boleto para o pagamento.</p>');

    // Adicionar anexo
    $caminho = 'pdf/tmp/';
    $ficheiro = $arquivo;

    $mail->AddAttachment($caminho.$ficheiro);

    // Enviar email
    $mail->Send();

    //echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
    >>>Aqui preciso da mensagem e depois destruir a sessão e redirecionar para index.
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    // Mensagens de erro do PHPMailer
    echo $e->errorMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Outras mensagens de erro
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que deve estar acontecendo é o fato de que o `header()` é uma instrução de cabelho para o browser, e ele acaba ignorando `alert()`.

Você poderia tentar redirecionar por JavaScript, escrevendo este texto:

```
<SCRIPT type='text/javascript'> 
    alert('O boleto foi enviado para o e-mail informado!');
    window.location.replace(\"index.php\");
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou... continua passando direto...

Comment: @xavier poderia colocar o código interio? Acredito que o código comece em um `try` correto? Tenta fazer um echo antes e um echo depois do `try/catch`. Remova também o `header()` se ainda não o fez.

Comment: Beleza Rodrigo. Deu certo da seguinte maneira: 
<?php
$refresh = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=index.php" />'; 
    echo('<script type="text/javascript">alert("O boleto foi enviado para o e-mail informado!")</script>');
 session_destroy();
 exit ($refresh);
    }
Assim deu certo. Esta forma está errada?

Comment: Se essa forma não é errada, tem como centralizar essa janela da mensagem no formulário?

Comment: Acho que não está errada não. Como voce destruiu já a session, o usuário não terá como fazer algo errado. Centralizar o alert do navegador você diz?

Comment: Sim. Centralizar na tela!!

Comment: @xavier Me desculpe, mas perguntei mais porque acredito que não tem como mudar o visual de um alert. Isto é algo do browser. Se quiser algo diferente vai ter que fazer o echo sair um html com um layout mesmo ou usar um outro layout pra você.

Comment: Obrigado pela a ajuda Dobrychtop e Rodrigo.